# Auto change Woocommerce order status Failed -> Canceled

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to automatically change Woocommerce orders with "Failed" status to "Cancel" status after 24h.
It means the customer has not been able to pay his order.

I have tried many things so far but was not able to make it work.
Here is the mu-plugin I have created :

```
    <?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_submitted', 'cancel_failed_orders' );
function cancel_failed_orders() {
    $days_delay = 1; 
    $one_day    = 24 * 60 * 60;
    $today      = strtotime( date('Y-m-d') );
    $failed_orders = (array) wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'        => -1,
        'status'       => 'wc-failed',
        'date_created' => '<' . ( $today - ($days_delay * $one_day) ),
    ) );
    if ( sizeof($failed_orders) > 0 ) {
        $cancelled_text = __("No successful payment", "woocommerce");
        foreach ( $failed_orders as $order ) {
            $order->update_status( 'wc-cancelled', $cancelled_text );
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone has any idea what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_submitted" action doesn't exists.
You can use "woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders" action.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with wp-cron job. To test it at full install WP Crontrol plugin so you can manualy run the cron job when you need it or wait 1 hour. Your cron job should be listed as name failed_orders_event .

Disable wp-cron and use server cron if you want execution on every hour with or without visitors. There is alot of info on the web.

```
add_action('failed_orders_event', 'check_failed_orders_every_hour');
// The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site
function failed_orders_event_activation() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'failed_orders_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'failed_orders_event');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'failed_orders_event_activation');

function check_failed_orders_every_hour() {
    $failed_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'        => -1,
        'status'       => 'failed',
    ));

    foreach ( $failed_orders as $order ) {
        $cancelled_text = __("No successful payment", "woocommerce");
        $order->update_status( 'cancelled',$cancelled_text);
    }
    
}
```